# Bootstrap 3 nav-collapse start collapsed only on mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

There are a lot of questions surrounding collapsing navbar, but I can't find this specific case, sorry if it's a duplicate anyway.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-default container">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Brand</a>
  </div>
    <div class="nav-collapse" id="navbar">
```

I am trying to have my navbar start collapsed on mobile (on page load). I found it works that way when I add `class="collapse"` to the `#navbar` div, but then on PC my navbar is hidden, unless I go to small resolution and toggle it.

Also in this implementation, the first click on collapse button "reopens" opened navbar on mobile.

Comment: Can you post the rest of your navbar html?

Comment: @lamelemon http://hastebin.com/erasuxotap.django - a bit ugly, copied from various sources, haven't cleaned up yet (indents)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is with:

```
<div class="nav-collapse" id="navbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
```

It should be `navbar-collapse`:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
```

Comment: Ah okay, that should have been obvious to me :X I'm guessing I copied the code from somebody using bootstrap 2, where it was nav-collapse? Or did he have a custom class? Just to clarify if you could :)

Comment: @iScrE4m Yes, it changed from version 2 to version 3.